# Couldn't resolve the error coming for mongodb atlas after deploying it on heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

In locally the application works perfectly but when i deployed it on heroku it showing errors on heroku logs. Also data wasn't added in mongoDb database. Actually in the application i used google-oauth login so in locally it works perfectly but not in heroku. I've also whitelisted my ip on mongodb atlas but still can't figure out why this error getting.

## Anybody help me plz.....

### Here is my prod.js file

```
module.exports = {
    googleClientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    googleClientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    cookieKey: process.env.COOKIE_KEY
}
```

### Here is my keys.js file

```
// Keys.js - figure out what credentials should return

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    // So we are in prodution - return the prod set of keys
    module.exports = require('./prod');
} else {
    // We are developement - return the dev keys
    module.exports = require('./dev');
}
```

### Here is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');

const app = express();

//Middleware
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// mongoDb Connection
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }).then(() => console.log('MongoDb Connect successfully'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));


// actual routes
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running in ${PORT}`));
```

### Actually i getting two different errors first was this

```
2019-09-02T06:28:59.760121+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2019-09-02T06:28:59.760149+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2019-09-02T06:28:59.760151+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763577+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763581+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:519
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763583+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763585+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763838+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763842+00:00 app[web.1]: at new MongooseError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:10:11)
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763844+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:519:11)
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763846+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:321:15)
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763848+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:24:10)
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763850+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763852+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-09-02T06:28:59.763854+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
```

### And the second one is this

```
2019-09-02T08:49:22.115492+00:00 app[web.1]: { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [productionproj-shard-00-00-qfouv.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to productionproj-shard-00-00-qfouv.mongodb.net:27017 closed]
```

## So on...... as same as above

### Here is my mongodb production url i've been added on heroku config vars

```
mongodb+srv://nansProdDeploy:nansProdDeploy@productionproj-qfouv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about whitelisting the correct ip address. When we put our application on heroku we must whitelist the ip by clicking **[ Allow Access From Anywhere ]** button and then click ok your ip will be 0.0.0.0/0 this ip will allow to access your deployed heroku application. When you are using your application locally at that point of you have to choose **[ Add Current Ip Address ]** to access your application locally